# Direction to locate the Torah seam

Tags: torah-reading, hagbah-gelilah

O.C. (location will be edited later) says that prior to *hagbah* (Torah lifting), the magbihah should roll the Torah so that the seam separating two pieces of parchment will be in the center when he lifts.

Is there any halacha dictating the direction to locate the seam? Forwards, backwards or in the direction that will confuse the *Ba'al Kri'ah* the next time he has to read :-?

Comment: Does it really say that in Shulchan Arukh OC? Where?

Comment: @DoubleAA Not prior to *hagbah*, but rather before *gelilah*, is stated in SA OC [147:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x522)

Comment: @ploni meaning the concern is it might split while being stored not while being lifted

Answer (score 7):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ([23:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.23.25?lang=bi)) writes that it should be rolled to the nearest seam, in order to minimize the rolling, out of respect for the *Sefer Torah*.

Comment: I'm surprised that *torach tzibbur* was not a factor in this consideration.

Comment: @DanF A minimal amount of rolling probably wouldn't count as *torach tzibbur*.